# Is there a shorter code for useState const?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am using react-native useState and have following const in the code. Was wondering if there is a shorter way to write this, since they are very similar.

```
const [oldPasswordValue, setOldPasswordValue] = useState('');
const [newPasswordValue, setNewPasswordValue] = useState('');
const [confirmPasswordValue, setConfirmPasswordValue] = useState('');
```

Comment: I think it's already shorter, by using `Destructuring assignment`

Comment: You could use a third-party hook, for example `useSetState` (https://github.com/streamich/react-use/blob/master/docs/useSetState.md). Where it merges changes into the current state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could do something like that

```
const oldPassword = useState('');
```

and when you try to read the value write this `oldPassword[0]` and if you want to update the value get the second index `oldPassword[1]`

here is a simple example

```js
let data = [1, 2]

// first way with destructring
let [el1, el2] = data;
console.log(el1, el2)

// second way by indexing
console.log(data[0], data[1])
```

Comment: :O how did you find that out? is there any link to it?

Comment: no need to link when you make destructuring that is mean you return with `array` so instead of giving each one a name you could access it by index in the `array` and in case of `useState` it returns with an array of two-element the first one is the `getter` and the second is the `setter`

Comment: @verunar check the answer again i add an example explain it

Answer (score -1):

Im not rly sure if there is any shorter version, or how would you even be posible to have shorter, you need value and setValue, also default state. In my opinion its as short as it can be.

Comment: I tried Joseph's solution in code, and it works! That said though, if I didn't know about this, and read someone else's code, I wouldn't understand it, so I think 'set...' is much more readable

Comment: also i dont know who went on this down arrow spree on this ticket, wasnt me, both answers and my question were down-arrowed

Comment: oh allright, i was surprised that i got down rated for even try to help :D